# vscode suggestion doesn't show me the little square color block near to the name variable

Tags: css, variables, colors, search-suggestion

this may seem trivial but it is important to me.

I work with a lot of variables in the :root, unfortunately when I want to use the variables in another file with var(), the little color block next to the name does not appear, just the name is present.
[block color appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YSzl.png)
[block color not here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTQoc.png)

It works when I am in the file where the :root{} is but not the others.

Comment: "_It works when I am in the file where the :root{} is but not the others_" Is that precisely what's happening? Or is it actually that it works in whichever file the variable you want the indicator for is defined, but not in another file that was imported by the file where it is defined?

Comment: Sorry, I'll make myself more clear

I have a main.scss file where I import all my .scss files like _components.scss, _layout.scss, _base.scss and so on and so forth.

In my _base.scss, I declare my :root{}, and in this file the suggestion show me the little block color near my variable name that i defined in the :root{}.(perfect case)

But, in others files, like _components_scss, it doesn't not.